# Find all documents where one or more nested keys exists

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to figure out how I could key all the documents where one or more nested keys exists. So take the following collection

[
        {_id = "setting1"
            ,name="setting1Name"
            ,description="This is the description"
            ,values = {     us ="good"
                            ,uk="great"

```
                }
        ,defaultvalues={    us ="good"
                        ,uk="great"
                        ,sp="bueno"
                    }
        ,position = "1"
        ,group="group1"
    },
    {_id = "setting2"
        ,name="setting2Name"
        ,description="This is the description"
        ,values = {     us ="good"
                    ,lu="great"
                }
        ,defaultvalues={    us ="good"
                        ,uk="great"
                        ,sp="bueno"
                    }
        ,position = "2"
        ,group="group2"
    }]
```

So I would like to find the documents where the key(s) in values in ['us','lu'].  I know how to do this

query = mongo.collection("settings").find({ "values.us" = {"$exists" = "true"} }    ) ;

but what would be the best way to extend that so if either "us" or "lu" exists return?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try using the '$or' operator.  I'm used to the php syntax, but you'll get the idea.

```
$where = array(
    '$or' => array(
        array('values.us' => array('$exists' => TRUE)),
        array('values.lu' => array('$exists' => TRUE))
    )
);

$query = $collection->find($where);
```